# How a chosen multiselect can be validated with JsValidator in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-chosen

I am using [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to convert a simple select in a multiselect like here...

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('media_formats', trans('medias::messages.valid_formats'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::select('media_formats[]', $media_formats, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'media_formats', 'multiple', 'data-chosen']) !!}
</div>
```

Trying to validate that some media_format element has been selected using [JsValidator](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) package...

```
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('Maravel\Media\Http\Requests\Admin\MediaResourceCreateRequest', '#create-edit-form' ) !!}
```

And finally, using the following rule at the Request class...

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'media_formats' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

The Laravel validation bag of errors returns the media format error, but it is not being printed anywhere. Why? It has to do with the fact that chosen hides the select element? I tried...

```
    {!! JsValidator::formRequest('Maravel\Media\Http\Requests\Admin\MediaResourceCreateRequest', '#create-edit-form' )->ignore('') !!}
```

with no success. Or it has to do with the fact that the field name is *media_formats[]* and not *media_formats*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the answer was in the two problems I was suspecting from. Doing...

```
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('Maravel\Media\Http\Requests\Admin\MediaResourceCreateRequest', '#create-edit-form' )->ignore('') !!}
```

...and if I do...

```
public function rules()
{
    return [           
        ...
        'media_formats[]' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

The error message gets printed because jquery validate looks for a input with the name 'media_formats[]' -with the brackets-. However, Laravel validation does not work this way and expects the name of the field without brackets.

So, I figured out a workaround to get all working. If in the request I do

```
public function rules()
{
    return [           
        ...
        'media_formats' => 'required|array',
    ];
}
```

And I change the view that is used in JsValidator and I add these lines just before rules parameter is set...

```
<?php
    foreach($validator['rules'] as $i=>$rule){
        foreach($rule as $j=>$rule_type){
            foreach($rule_type as $k=>$rule_option){
                if($rule_option[0] == "Array") {
                    $validator['rules'][$i."[]"] = $validator['rules'][$i];
                    unset($validator['rules'][$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    };
?>

rules: <?php echo json_encode($validator['rules']); ?>
```

I am able to change the rules array and concatenate the '[]' to the fields that are validated as arrays so jquery validate can find the element where the error should appear.

The view used by JsValidator can be changed on the JsValidator config file.

```
return array(

/*
 * Default view used to render Javascript validation code
 */
'view' => 'jsvalidation::custom_bootstrap',
```